# Cannot find symbol: method findViewByID(int)

Tags: java, android

Been trying to figure out the problem for the last two hours. The solutions I have seen and tried are as follows:

- Invalidate caches/restart
- getView().findViewByID(R.id.button) or rootView.findViewById(R.id.button)
- Casing

  ```
        Button popUp = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button);
  ```

[This is the video that I was following to create this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Typo. It's `findViewById()`, not `findViewByID()`. The last `d` is lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Button popUp = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button);
```

with this

```
Button popUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

You are writing **findViewByID** it's not allowed in android write **findViewById**

Answer (score 0):

https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/how-to-make-sense-of-android-crash-logs

I think this is an article that would prove very useful to find errors like that.  You were probably throwing an error in your run log at the exact line you had this issue at, which forces you to look at the exact spot of your mistake.

But like the comment on it said, you had a simple typo. Wasn't the word with your mistake turning red?  If not I'd try a different IDE such as android studio.

Regards,